# The only problem is it throws "IndentationError: " when I use try except with "with open('file_name', 'mode') as file_handler:"

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io, indentation

As far as I know, I've done the indentation right, I also tried the same code in another text editor, but it throws the same error.

It throws "IndentationError: " when I use try except with "with open('file_name', 'mode') as file_handler:"

python3 test2.py
File "test2.py", line 9
except IOError:
^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

I learned similar articles, and it says indent consciously. I also tried with tab and 4 spaces, but it's not working either way.
Maybe it's a stupid mistake that I'm not getting.
Please help me, And I'd be grateful to get suggestions to do things better in this code so that I could learn something.

```
f_name = input("enter a file name:: ")

if f_name == 'na na boo boo':
    print(f"\n{f_name} TO YOU - You have been punk'd!\n")
    exit()
try:
    with open(f_name, 'r') as f_hand:

except IOError:
    print(f'File missing:: {f_name}.')
    exit()

    floating_points = []

    for line in f_hand:

        if line.startswith('X-DSPAM') :
            start_index_pos = line.find(':')
            start_index_pos = float(start_index_pos)
            floating_points.append(start_index_pos)
    print("The floating points are::\n")

    for floating_point in floating_points:
        print(floating_point)
    print(f"There are {len(floating_points)} items on the list and they sum to {sum(floating_points)}.")
```

Comment: You can't interrupt the `with` statement with the `except` clause of the `try` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot interrupt the `with` statement with the `except` clause of the `try` statement. It has to be completed first. Some of the code can be moved out of the `with` statement and placed before or after (as appropriate) the `try` statement

```
floating_points = []

try:
    with open(f_name, 'r') as f_hand:
        for line in f_hand:
            if line.startswith('X-DSPAM') :
                start_index_pos = line.find(':')
                start_index_pos = float(start_index_pos)
                floating_points.append(start_index_pos)
except FileNotFoundError:
    print(f'File missing:: {f_name}.')
    exit()

print("The floating points are::\n")
for floating_point in floating_points:
    print(floating_point)
print(f"There are {len(floating_points)} items on the list and they sum to {sum(floating_points)}.")
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand it. Does the file keep on running till the indentation of with statement is de-indented or it stops after if block. if the file keeps on running till the with block runs then it makes sense to de-indent after for block.

Comment: It's like any other compound statement. The first line ends with a colon, and all lines indentation at least as much as the next line belong to the compound statement. You got an error here because the body was empty.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is completely wrong, you don't use context manager just to open a file, for that, we have open(), we use `with` as a context manager so that it'll take care of closing the file later automatically.

and the syntax is wrong, you can't just leave the `with` statement hanging with a `:`, the operations on the file must be inside the with indentation.

anyway here is the right code

```
f_name = input("enter a file name:: ")

if f_name == 'na na boo boo':
    print(f"\n{f_name} TO YOU - You have been punk'd!\n")
    exit()
try:
    with open(f_name, 'r') as f_hand:
        floating_points = []

        for line in f_hand:

            if line.startswith('X-DSPAM'):
                start_index_pos = line.find(':')
                start_index_pos = float(start_index_pos)
                floating_points.append(start_index_pos)
        print("The floating points are::\n")

        for floating_point in floating_points:
            print(floating_point)
        print(f"There are {len(floating_points)} items on the list and they sum to {sum(floating_points)}.")
except IOError:
    print(f'File missing:: {f_name}.')
    exit()
```

Comment: Yeah, I got it but I think it's more memory efficient to move except block after for block and floating_points to top because after for block we're actually working within the code not on the file. as @chepner did. Thank you.

Comment: Memory has nothing to do with it. There's no new scope created; the `with` statement just delimits when the context manager's `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods are called, that's all.